# Using Amazon Cognito Identity User Pools

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Yesterday I was excited to see the roll out of the new user pools beta. I was able to get the auth working just fine and have no problem signing up a user, signing a user in. However, I am having trouble going from there to allowing persistence. Which comes from storing the login credentials.

In the sample app, the AWSSignInProvider (used for Facebook, Google,Twitter) class extends AWSIdentityProvider. Do I need to build out a separate class for the Cognito User Pool as well that will refresh the token? I cannot find much documentation or examples on this.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to store the user's access token somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito mobile SDKs persist the tokens for you once the user is logged in. The next time you call the [getSession](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityUser.html#//api/name/getSession) method for a user, the SDK will directly return the cached tokens or automatically refresh them for you if there is a valid refresh token.

Only if the refresh token is expired, the user will be asked to enter his username and password. Hope this solves your persistence requirement.

Comment: Thats what I noticed. So I ended up not using the the Identity Manager all-together since the SDK handles the persistence on its own.  What will cause the refresh token to expire?

Comment: Refresh tokens are valid for 30 days by default. One the limit is reached, they expire.